# rust find out closure annotation / signature

Tags: rust, closures

### Question:

How do I find a closure's signature? Specifically, how do I figure out if a closure is making reference to my local variable or not?

### Background:

I think the closure used in `pool.install` should make immutable reference to my local variable `book`, but the compiler is not complaining. So I'm trying to figure out the closure signature used in `pool.install`, thinking this information may help me understand what's happening.

```rust
    let pool = rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new().build().unwrap();
    loop {
        let book = get_book.select_next_some().await;
        while mut_tasks.is_empty() {
            select! {
                task = rx_grammar_req.select_next_some() => {
                    match task.req {
                        Req::M {..} => mut_tasks.push(ready(task)),
                        Req::R {..} => {

                            // Q: how do I figure out the closure's signature?
                            pool.install(|| run_ref_task(&book, task));

                        }
                    };
                },
            }
        }

        get_book.push(ready(book));
        let mut queries = FuturesUnordered::new();
        loop {
            select! {
                book = queries.select_next_some() => {
                    get_book.push(ready(book));
                    if mut_tasks.is_empty() && queries.is_empty() { break; }
                },
                book = get_book.select_next_some() => {
                    if let Some(task) = mut_tasks.next().await {
                        queries.push(run_mut_task(book, task));
                    } else {
                        get_book.push(ready(book));
                        if queries.is_empty() { break; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closure's signature is dictated by the function signature of `ThreadPool::install`:

```
    pub fn install<OP, R>(&self, op: OP) -> R
    where
        OP: FnOnce() -> R + Send,
        R: Send { ... }
```

Thus, the signature of your closure is `() -> R` where `R` is the output of `run_ref_task(&book, task)`.

I'm assuming that you're not actually interested in the *signature* of the closure but rather in what the closure *captures*. In this case, `book` is captured by reference and `task` is captured by value or copied if its type implements `Copy`.

Further reading about closure capture modes and `FnOnce` / `FnMut` / `Fn` can be found here:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#capture-modes
https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#call-traits-and-coercions